# How can I accss this and that in class method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to access this and that in class method?

This is simple websocket stream manager class

Class manage several websocket connections,

and has open, close, error, message handlers.

```js
class Stream implements IStream {

  private ws: WebSocket[] = []
  private params: string[] = []
  private streamCount: number = 2

  constructor(url: string, params: string[]) {
    this.url = url
    this.params = params
  }

  private _onOpen() {

    // I want to use this and that ...
    // this: Websocket
    // that: Stream
    this.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        params: that.params
      })
    )
  }

  private _onMessage(msg: Buffer) {
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg.toString())
    console.log(jsonObj)
  }

  private _onClose(msg) {
    console.error(msg)

    // I want to use this and that ...
    // this: WebSocket
    // that: Stream
    const idx = that.ws.indexOf(this)
    that.ws[idx] = new WebSocket(that.url)
  }

  private _setWsListener(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.on('error', console.error)
    ws.on('open', this._onOpen)
    ws.on('message', this._onMessage)
    ws.on('close', this._onClose)
  }

  public listen() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.streamCount; i++) {
      const conn = new WebSocket(this.url)
      this._setWsListener(conn)
      this.ws.push(conn)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this way

```js
  private _setWsListener(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.on('error', console.error.bind(this))
    ws.on('open', this._onOpen.bind(this))
    ws.on('message', this._onMessage.bind(this))
    ws.on('close', this._onClose.bind(this))
  }
```

But in this case, I can't access Websocket instance..

And this way,

```js
  private _setWsListener(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.on('error', console.error)
    ws.on('open', this._onOpen(ws))
    ws.on('message', this._onMessage)
    ws.on('close', this._onClose)
  }
```

I have to make thunk anonymous function

```js
  private _onOpen(ws: WebSocket) {
    return () => {
      ws.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          method: 'SUBSCRIBE',
          params: this.params,
          id: 1
        })
      )
    }
  }
```

Which makes more complicate code..

Is there another way more simple and direct?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and immediately see the problem you're having without seeing problems you're not having. There shouldn't be any reliance on private/third-party/missing code unless you're asking about a particular library or something (and then it should be tagged.) You can use [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to check if it meets that criteria (but please post *plaintext* here and not just a link to a playground).  Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I get `this` but what is `that`?

Comment: The approach of binding the handlers to `this` is correct.  I do not understand why `that` is needed, I would remove it.  If you need to access the stream context, use `this`, if you need the ws, you have it at `this.ws`.

Comment: @tadman that is what I want to use..

Comment: Unless you're trying to reproduce [a famous comedy routine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_on_First%3F) you'll have to be a lot more clear about exactly what you're doing. You haven't defined `that` anywhere, and it's not part of TS or JS, so... what are you doing? Third base?

Comment: @Razumov Because I want to know which connection is closed(opened) and want to use the exact connection

Comment: @user3077593 my bad, I overlooked that.  In that case, it does make sense to have a scope where you can access the ws.  Your anonymous function approach works, or you could create an inner class, one-per websocket.  I would recomment the inner class - it will make reasoning about the current ws easier.

Comment: Anon func?  `ws.on('open', (e) => this._onOpen(e, ws))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any method on `Stream`, the `this` keyword should refer to the `Stream` instance. So do it the other way round, pass the `WebSocket` instance as a parameter to the methods that need it - just like you already do with `_setWsListener`. Then you can use `bind` to bind both the `this` context as well as the first parameter.

```
class Stream implements IStream {
  private ws: WebSocket[] = []
  private params: string[] = []
  private streamCount: number = 2

  constructor(url: string, params: string[]) {
    this.url = url
    this.params = params
  }

  private _onOpen(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        params: this.params
      })
    )
  }

  private _onMessage(msg: Buffer) {
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg.toString())
    console.log(jsonObj)
  }

  private _onClose(ws: WebSocket, msg) {
    console.error(msg)

    const idx = this.ws.indexOf(ws)
    this.ws[idx] = new WebSocket(this.url)
    this._setWsListener(this.ws[idx]) // sic!
  }

  private _setWsListener(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.on('error', console.error)
    ws.on('open', this._onOpen.bind(this, ws))
    ws.on('message', this._onMessage.bind(this))
    ws.on('close', this._onClose.bind(this, ws))
  }

  public listen() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.streamCount; i++) {
      const conn = new WebSocket(this.url)
      this._setWsListener(conn)
      this.ws.push(conn)
    }
  }
}
```

As an alternative to `bind`, you can use arrow functions:

```
  private _setWsListener(ws: WebSocket) {
    ws.on('error', err => console.error(err))
    ws.on('open', msg => this._onOpen(ws, msg))
    ws.on('message', msg => this._onMessage(msg))
    ws.on('close', msg => this._onClose(ws, msg))
  }
```